# how do i configure/install jocaml on windows

Tags: ocaml

The only instructions I could find are here: http://eigenclass.org/hiki/fast-widefinder and on the old jocaml site.

When I try to configure using ./configure, it says jocaml and companion ocaml versions are mismatched. I tried using jocaml 3.11.0 and ocaml 3.11.0. How to go forward?

I have read in the mailing lists that support for windows is untested. Does it mean that I cannot use jocaml on windows?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those instructions should still be ok, but you should get the latest JoCaml sources. The [JoCaml website](http://jocaml.inria.fr/cvs.html) hasn't updated its pointers yet. You should checkout using:

```
 svn checkout http://caml.inria.fr/svn/ocaml/branches/jocamltrunk
```

(as per [Ocaml](http://caml.inria.fr/ocaml/anonsvn.en.html)'s subversion instructions)

Otherwise, [apparently](http://yquem.inria.fr/pipermail/jocaml-list/2009-June/000114.html), your JoCaml & Ocaml versions should work together. If you still encounter problems, you should ask the [JoCaml mailing list.](http://yquem.inria.fr/cgi-bin/mailman/listinfo/jocaml-list)

Answer (score 1):

README says that `companion ocaml` is optional, so that shouldn't be the problem.

The real problem, as far as I tried, is that the Makefile's for windows (msvc) are not in sync with jocaml changes. So one needs to explore diffs and update Makefiles manually. I think it is quite possible with some effort.